# For two continous independent r.v.s what does $\int_Y f_x(y)dy$ mean?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, change-of-variable

Does the $y$ variable act as an indicator function such that $f_X(y)$ only has values for elements $\omega \in X\cap Y$ ?

Is  $\int_Y f_x(y)dy$ the probability distribution of $X$ over the sample space of $Y$?

Forgive me if some of the terminology is inaccurate as I study this course in another language. This has been bothering me for some time and I would appreciate it in the extreme if somebody could enlighten me.

Backstory:

In one of the exercises of my probabilit we have two independent continous r.v.s' $X \geq 0$ and $Y \geq 0$ and we are supposed to show that their product:

$f_{XY}(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{y} f_X(\frac{x}{y})f_y(y)dy=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{y} f_X(y)f_y(\frac{x}{y})dy$

I can get the first part of it by setting $Z=XY$ and $U=Y$ but what I have a hard time understanding is the second part what does $f_X(y)$ mean? The only thing I could think of was that you could:

$P(XY\leq x)= \int_Y P(Y \leq x/y|X=y)P(X=y)$

Then by independence the condition falls away and you would get the second term, but that does not seem right since $P(X=y) =0$ as they are both continous right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be more accurate to write $P(XY \le x) = \int_0^\infty P(Y \le x/y) f_X(y) \, dy$, where $f_X$ is the marginal density of $X$.

This comes from the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).
If $1_{XY \le x}$ denotes the [indicator random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) for the event $\{XY \le x\}$ then
$$P(XY \le x) = E[1_{XY \le x}] = E[E[1_{XY \le x} \mid X]] = \int_0^\infty E[1_{XY \le x} \mid X=y] f_X(y) \, dy
= \int_0^\infty P(Y \le x/y) f_X(y) \, dy.$$

Comment: Could it just as well be xdx or udu as ydy? Does the name of the variable inside fx matter when marginalizing?

Comment: @Imudaine The dummy variable doesn't matter, but $x$ is a bad choice here because it is already used in "$P(XY \le x)$."

Comment: Ok, I guess they were making sure that you knew that that was a dummy variable. Thank you!